# How do I downgrade Make from 4.2.1 to 3.82?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I want to use make version 3.82, so I am downgrading from version 4.2.1.

After downloading the make-3.82.tar.gz file from the https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/ site, extract the file and run ./configure ./build.sh to create a make file.
if run the make file, I get an error called Segmentation error (core dump).

How do I make make work properly?

Comment: Did you remove version 4.2.1?  How?  Did you install the new version how?  My guess is that you using an incompatible library (or didn't reload the libraries with ldconfig).  The other thing you need to do for us is set `ulimit -c unlimited`, rerun your make, then gdb on the core file and tell us the stacktrace.  You might need to recompile make with debug output (CFLAGS -g3 for gcc)

Comment: I don't know if embedded-linux implies no distrubution, but if you are using one (debian, redhat etc) then you can often find binaries pre-compiled.  Why are you down-grading in the first place?

Comment: Solved after running ulimit -c unlimited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `ulimit -c unlimited` then re-run make, it will generate a core file that you can inspect with gdb to see what happened.  You may need to recompile make with -g3 or similar to ensure the binary contains debugging information.